# Can’t find file to patch at input line 3

Tags: diff, patch

I generated a patch using the `diff` command with the number of context lines as 1 (`-c` option). My patch file contents:

```
*** /home/sk/abc/def/src/klm/a.py 2015-05-18 16:25:50.348398554 +0530
--- /opt/abc/def/ghi/klm/a.py  2015-05-18 14:27:13.860503469 +0530
***************
*** 72,73 ****
--- 72,74 ----
              output, error, rCommand = "", "", ""
+             import subprocess
              rCommand = self.copyCmd % (self.executor_hostname, self.testId, self.testId)
```

When I tried to apply the patch using these commands,

```
cd /
patch -p0 < sg.patch
```

I got this output,

```
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|*** /home/sk/abc/def/src/klm/a.py  2015-05-18 16:25:50.348398554 +0530
|--- /opt/abc/def/ghi/klm/a.py  2015-05-18 17:10:48.368670076 +0530
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

Why doesn't the patch command take the file name in second line as the file to patch?

Comment: hi javabrett, thanks for your info.. i have changed the question and its error message...

Comment: Are both of the files present?

Answer (score 13):

You need to be in the root directory to apply the patch with an absolute path, and apply the `-p0` option.  See also [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167216/how-can-i-apply-a-p0-patch-from-any-working-directory).