# How to apply simple patch (reverse detected)

Tags: diff, patch

I'm trying to create and apply a simple patch to fix a [bug with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307516/gradle-finds-wrong-java-home-even-though-its-correctly-set).

I copy the file (/usr/bin/gradle) to my working directory, then make the change.  I then create the patch:

```
diff -u /usr/bin/gradle gradle > gradle.patch
```

Then I attempt to apply it:

```
sudo patch < gradle.patch
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
```

If I proceed anyway, it fails.  I have tried generating the patch with the files reversed, and in this case it applies "successfully," but does nothing.

The generated patch looks like this:

```
--- /usr/bin/gradle 2013-09-09 16:47:58.000000000 -0400
+++ gradle  2015-10-13 11:39:36.005269565 -0400
@@ -67,7 +67,8 @@

 CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/lib/gradle-launcher-1.4.jar

-export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
+# commenting out as per (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22309017)
+# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

 # Determine the Java command to use to start the JVM.
 if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
```

I have tried editing the file paths at the top of the patch to both be /usr/bin/gradle, however this doesn't help.

I have also tried passing -p0, in which case it give:

```
Ignoring potentially dangerous file name /usr/bin/gradle
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- /usr/bin/gradle    2013-09-09 16:47:58.000000000 -0400
|+++ /usr/bin/gradle    2015-10-13 11:39:36.005269565 -0400
--------------------------
File to patch: /usr/bin/gradle
File /usr/bin/gradle is not a regular file -- refusing to patch
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file /usr/bin/gradle.rej
```

When I specify the file in this case, it still fails.

This seems like a simple task, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to patch the right file.

The way you call it, it will try to patch the new file and thus correctly assumes a reversed patch.

Try to copy an old version of the file to your current directory and the patch will apply.

Regarding your `-p0` test: do you have permission to modify /usr/bin/gradle?
Do you have permission to create files in /usr/bin?

Also note that there are deviating rules for getting the filename to patch.

The rules used by `gpatch` are different from both the original patch and the POSIX patch standard.

Note that the "not a regular file" message is specific to `gpatch`. Please list the file `/usr/bin/gradle`. The message is only printed when the file is not a regular file, so something looks strange.

So the solution is:

`patch` only patches plain files but the file you like to patch is a symbolic link.

If you have a copy of the plain (old version) file in your current directory, patch will do what you expect.

BTW: the usual rule for getting the file name to patch is to look for the shortest name as the usual naming convention is to use:

`file.orig`

and

`file`

Comment: If I reverse the file names in the patch header, i.e., first one is gradle, second one is /usr/bin/gradle, then the behaviour is the same.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Re permissions, yes, running with sudo.

Comment: See what you mean now, yes it does apply in my original directory in that case.  Shouldn't it apply in /usr/bin if the second line is /usr/bin/gradle?

Comment: Bingo: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Sep  9  2013 /usr/bin/gradle -> ../share/gradle/bin/gradle

Comment: Except now when I update the patch to look for /usr/share/bin/gradle, it doesn't see the path "couldn't find file to patch at input line 3".  Why is it looking at line 3, aren't the first two lines the file paths?

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a trick to getting diff to generate the patch in a format expected by patch? -u doesn't seem to be doing it.  The file names are still on lines 1 and 2, whereas patch seems to be expecting the file on line 3...

Comment: If you believe that your patch looks at line 3, it seems to have a bug. The format from `diff -u` is dedicated to `patch`.

Comment: Solved the final issue [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167250/36963). Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, but this is in conflict with the POSIX standard that does not permit such non-orthogonal behavior.

Comment: Not following your there, @schily, what non-orthogonal behaviour?

Comment: It seems that newer versions of `gpatch` do not treat all filenames the same.